# Missing s3 key error in static site served by node.js

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3

I compiled and pushed my vue app onto S3 and I am serving it in my node/express app using [s3-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-proxy). I can navigate to my app at `/` just fine. However, if I navigate directly to any other route such as `/login`, I get an `Missing S3 key` error. I understand that the root cause is there's no file in my bucket called `login`, but I'm not quite sure how to get around the issue. Here's my code:

```
app.get(
      "/*",
      s3Proxy({
      bucket: config.AWS.S3.UI.BUCKET,
      accessKeyId: config.AWS.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
      secretAccessKey: config.AWS.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
      defaultKey: "index.html",
    })
  );
```

Any advice would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a middleware:

```js
app.get(
    "/*",
    (req, res, next) => {
        req.url = "/"
        next()
    },
    s3Proxy({
        bucket: config.AWS.S3.UI.BUCKET,
        accessKeyId: config.AWS.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: config.AWS.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        defaultKey: "index.html",
    })
);
```

`s3Proxy()` creates a [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html), which is just a function with 3 arguments. You can create your own middlewares modifying the request. Changing `req.url` won't redirect the client to the root page, the vue application will be able to handle the routing as intended.

Note that any other middleware you were to put after s3Proxy will receive modified requests too.

Comment: thanks @yuri! that didn't work for me but i checked the `s3Proxy()` code and it actually uses `req.originalUrl` so I did `req.originalUrl = "/";` and that did the trick. However, files in my `assets` folder wont load correctly. but i've got a workaround it for now. thank you for your help!

Comment: @JohnGrayson glad I could help! Even if my answer wasn't thoroughly thought through (I completely forgot about assets directories). Most common approach is testing whether or not a file with a given path exists, and if not, returning the index page, akin to nginx's `try_files`. Sometimes it makes sense to filter out which requests should be looked up first, e.g. by checking the file extension, or lack thereof. In case of express, it can be done with error handlers. I can edit the answer if needed